# how to form key=value terraform output

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to build a simple module that takes a gcp project as input and outputs the default_service_account

how it is called from main.tf at root

```
module "default_service_accounts" {
  source = "./default_service_accounts"
  for_each = module.projects.enterprise_projects
  project_name = each.key
  project_id = each.value
}
```

default_service_accounts input.tf:

```
variable "project_name" {
  description   = "project_name"
  type = string
}

variable "project_id" {
  description = "project_id"
  type = string
}
```

default_service_accounts main.tf

```
data "google_compute_default_service_account" "default" {
  project = var.project_id
}
```

default_service_accounts outputs.tf

```
output "output" {
    value = {
        (var.project_name) = data.google_compute_default_service_account.default.email
    }
}
```

then I would like to pass it in to another module:

```
module "compute" {
  source        = "./compute"
  projects      = module.projects.enterprise_projects
  default_service_accounts = module.default_service_accounts.output
}
```

and access it like so within that module:

```
var.default_service_accounts["myproject"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have your understanding of outputs a little muddled. You don't need to return a map from project name to DSA from within the DSAs module - the calling module will already make that map for you. Or at least, a map from project name to the complete DSA module instance, from which you can access the email output.

You should be able to do what you are after by altering `default_service_accounts/outputs.tf` to

```
output "account_email" {
    value = data.google_compute_default_service_account.default.email
}
```

then you will be able to use `module.default_service_accounts["myproject"].account_email`; i.e., you would pass the collection of module instances into the `compute` module with

```
module "compute" {
  source        = "./compute"
  projects      = module.projects.enterprise_projects
  default_service_accounts = module.default_service_accounts # <== note the removal of the output from this line
}
```

and you would access the values as `var.default_service_accounts["myproject"].account_email`.

The variables in the `compute` module would be something like

```
variable "projects" {
  description = "..."
  type = map(string)
}
variable "default_service_accounts" {
  description = "..."
  type = map(object(
    account_email = string
  ))
}
```

When you specify a `map` type variable, you are only specifying the type of the *value* of the map, the key is always a string.

---

If you really want to pass just a map from project name to default service account email, you can build that with

```
locals {
  service_accounts = {
    for project_name, dsa in module.default_service_accounts: 
      project_name => dsa.account_email
  }
}
```

then use that like

```
module "compute" {
  source        = "./compute"
  projects      = module.projects.enterprise_projects
  default_service_accounts = local.service_accounts  # <== here's the use of that new local variable
}
```

and within the `compute` module you can access the values exactly as you've shown at the end of your question (`var.default_service_accounts["myproject"]`).

In this case the variables for the `compute` module would look like

```
variable "projects" {
  description = "..."
  type = map(string)
}
variable "default_service_accounts" {
  description = "..."
  type = map(string)
}
```

since the `default_service_accounts` variable now maps directly from project name to service account email address (a string).

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!! 

the syntax is taking awhile to get used to. but I think I understand now. you are accessing an instance of the module by the key property.

what should my variable type in compute be declared as?

i currently have 
variable "default_service_accounts" {
  description = "default service accounts"
  type = ?
}

Comment: I've added to the answer to describe the variable types